# zsh: using "less -R" as READNULLCMD

Tags: zsh

Now, I'm pretty sure of the limitation here. But let's step back.

The simple statement

```
 READNULLCMD="less -R"
```

doesn't work, generating the following error:

```
$ <basic.tex                                                                            
zsh: command not found: less -R
```

OK. Pretty sure this is because, by default, zsh doesn't split string variables at every space. Wherever zsh is using this variable, it's using $READNULLCMD where it should be using ${=READNULLCMD}, to ensure the option argument is properly separated from the command by a normal space. See this discussion from way back in 1996(!):
http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/1996/msg00299.html

So, what's the best way around this, without setting SH_WORD_SPLIT (which I don't want 99% of the time)?

So far, my best idea is assigning READNULLCMD to a simple zsh script which just calls "less -R" on STDIN. e.g.

```
#!/opt/local/bin/zsh
less -R /dev/stdin
```

Unfortunately this seems to be a non-starter as less used in this fashion for some reason misses the first few lines on input from /dev/stdin.

Anybody have any better ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not that less doesn't read its environment variables (LESS or LESSOPEN). The problem is that the READNULLCMD is not invoked as you might think.

```
<foo
```

does not translate into

```
less $LESS foo
```

but rather to something like

```
cat foo | less $LESS
```

or, perhaps

```
cat foo $LESSOPEN | less $LESS
```

I guess that you (like me) want to use -R to obtain syntax coloring (by using src-hilite-lesspipe.sh in LESSOPEN, which in turn uses the "source-highlight" utility). The problem with the latter two styles of invocation is that src-hilite-lesspipe.sh (embedded in $LESSOPEN) will not receive a filename, and hence it will not be able to deduce the file type (via the --infer-lang option to "source-highligt"). Without a filename suffix, "source-highlight" will revert to "no highlighting".

You can obtain syntax coloring in READNULLCMD, but in a rather useless way. This by specifying the language explicitly via the --lang-def option. However, you'll have as little clue as "source-higlight", since the there's no file name when the data is passed anonymously through the pipe. Maybe there's a way to do a on-the-fly heuristic parser and deduce it by contents, but then you've for sure left this little exercise.

Comment: I eventually figured all this out, although you're the first person to clearly articulate the issue here. Even though my original goal can't be feasibly reached, I'm going to "accept" this answer for providing the clearest explanation to the next person who comes along.

Answer (score 1):

`export LESS=…` may be a good solution exclusively for `less` and if you want such behavior the default in all cases, but if you want more generic one then you can use functions:

```
function _-readnullcmd()
{
    less -R
}
READNULLCMD=_-readnullcmd
```

(`_-` or `readnullcmd` have no special meaning just the former never appears in any distributed zsh script and the latter indicates the purpose of the function).

Comment: It doesn't appear this works either. Specifically, I am trying to enable syntax highlighting through source-highlight when using the "<file" syntax. Using this approach, "echo $READNULLCMD" confirms "_-readnullcmd", but I don't see my syntax highlighting. Perhaps there is another reason for that? Is it possible to verify if "less" is started with the "-R" flag?

Comment: The only other component necessary to source-highlight in less is its highlight script, called via the .zshrc line "export LESSOPEN="| /opt/local/bin/src-hilite-lesspipe.sh %s"". Correct me if I'm wrong, but this should be quite visible to our new function. Perhaps this would work more expectedly if I call this script directly, assuring that $LESS=" -R ". I'll have to take a look at things and see if that works.

Comment: @marshaul Yes, it should be perfectly visible. There are at least two differences between READNULLCMD and using less manually though: first, with `READNULLCMD` less won’t possibly get a filename. Second, aliases are not expanded. If highlighting scripts relies on the extension then it won’t work like `LESSOPEN='|lesspipe %s'` does not enable listing archive contents when `READNULLCMD=less ; <arch.tar.gz`.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `$LESS` env var to the options you always want to have in `less`.

So don't touch `READNULLCMD` and use `export LESS="R"` (and other options you want) in your zshrc.

Comment: For whatever reason, $LESS is ignored when READNULLCMD is executed. I already had this in my environment, to no avail. =(

Comment: As I mention above, what I'm actually trying to do here is syntax highlighting via source-highlight. This depends on two variable assignments in the .zshrc, namely $LESS=" -R " (should be the same as "R") and "export LESSOPEN="| /opt/local/bin/src-hilite-lesspipe.sh %s"". I suppose it's possible it's $LESSOPEN which is being ignored, rather than $LESS. I don't know enough about how zsh calls the pager to determine this.

Comment: For me, running `<my_file` opens less with my `$LESS` options. If you have two potential problems, try to find which one is the actual issue. Give us instructions to reproduce your problem to see if we have it.