# Access file name (extension) with READNULLCMD

Tags: zsh

A nice shortcut in Zsh for `cat`ting files is, with Python file type for example:

```
<somefile.py
```

But it's much nicer if that file is syntax-highlighted.  So the trick is to use a tool like [bat](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat) instead of the default `cat`:

```
READNULLCMD=bat
```

This actually works when a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) is present since Bat will look for it.  BUT, the file type detection by extension might not be possible since the input is simply seen as `STDIN`.  And since most files don't have a shebang line, file name extension is a necessary fallback in order to detect file type.

There is [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14059061/326516) for debugging READNULLCMD, using a function.  I've tried wrapping in `set -x`, grepping `env`, etc, but not finding a way to see the name.  If I could see the name, then something like this could be used:

```
mynullcmd() { bat -l $stdin_filename:x } # get extension and use as file type
READNULLCMD=mynullcmd
```

**Question:** Is there some way for Zsh to know what's being passed in as STDIN?  Can it know that the command contained `somefile.py`?

Comment: Yes, I realize I could just type `bat somefile.py`, but I really like the `<` shortcut.

Comment: I think the only option would be if there is a way to find the name of the file opened for standard input. By the time `READNULLCMD` is opened, input has already been redirected and there's no reason for it to receive a file name as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Settle for an alias, like `c` is short for `cat` equivalent:

```
alias c=bat
c somefile.py
```

Other viable highlighters include [coderay](https://github.com/rubychan/coderay) and [pygmentize](https://pygments.org/docs/cmdline/), but I've found `bat` to be the most capable in speed and breadth of language support.